# Проблема с мешем при соединении со скелетом

Tags: model, blender

Когда я присоединила скелет с моделью, на нём появились какие-то заломы, когда я перешла в Pose mod. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть из-за неправильной позы модели. Попробуйте переместить модель в более правильную позу и проверить заломы. Также проверьте вершины и полигоны модели на наличие ошибок и попробуйте исправить их.